# Residue fields at points on $\mathbb{A}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, function-fields

Let $k=\bar k$ be a field. I'm trying to "write down" the residue fields at various points on $\mathbb{A}^n=\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$, but am having some trouble with the non-closed points. The definition I'm using is that residue field at a point $x$ on an integral scheme $X$ is the residue field of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_x$. Thus, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a point on the affine scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ then the residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$ is $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$, which is isomorphic to the fraction field of $A/\mathfrak{p}$.

On $\mathbb{A}^1=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ these fields are not hard to determine. The only points are the generic point $(0)$ and the closed points $(x-a)$ for $a\in k$. Clearly the residue field at the generic point (i.e., the function field) is $k(x)$ and the residue fields at closed points are all just $k$.

Already for $\mathbb{A}^2$, though, I'm finding this a bit trickier. The points in this case are again $(0)$ (generic), $(x-a,y-b)$ for $a,b\in k$ (closed), and $(f)$ for $f\in k[x,y]$ irreducible (nonclosed). The function field at the generic point is clearly $k(x,y)$, and it's also not hard to see that the function fields at closed points are all $k$. But what do we get for the function field at a nonclosed point $(f)$? I *think* this should come out to be an algebraic extension of a transcendence degree 1 extension of $k$, but would like some clarification on this. My thoughts are as follows. Given $f\in k[x,y]$ irreducible, the function field, which we denote $k(f)$, will be the fraction field of $k[x,y]/(f)$. Setting $R=k[x]$ and $g(y)=f(x,y)\in R[y]$, we have $k[x,y]/(f)=R[y]/(g(y))$, which I believe is isomorphic to $R(\alpha)$, where $\alpha\in \overline{k(x)}$ satisfies $g(\alpha)=0$, i.e., is a root of a polynomial equation with coefficients in $k[x]$. Thus, the fraction field of $k[x,y]/(f)$ should be an algebraic extension of $k(x)$. Morally, this feels right to me in that the various function fields one obtains for $\mathbb A^2$ include transcendence degree 0,1,2 extensions of $k$. What makes me somewhat skeptical is the choice $R=k[x]$ was completely arbitrary. The same reasoning would also show that $k(f)$ is an algebraic extension of $k(y)$. In either case, $k(f)$ seems to be a trans. degree 1 extension of $k$, but the degrees $[k(f):k(x)]$ and $[k(f):k(y)]$ need not be equal, which I find a bit disturbing. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

In the general case $\mathbb{A}^n$, what I expect then is that the function fields are again $k$ at the generic point, $k(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ at the closed points, and ... transcendence degree $n-1$ extensions of $k$ at the nonclosed other points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example. Consider an elliptic curve, for argument's sake
$$y^2=x^3+x$$
over $k=\Bbb C$. The residue field at its generic point is the fraction field of
$$\frac{\Bbb C[x,y]}{(y^2-x^3-x)}.$$
This is $\Bbb C(x)[y]$ where $y$ is a square root of $x^3+x$, so a quadratic
extension of $\Bbb C(x)$ and also it is
$\Bbb C(y)[x]$ where $x$ is a root of the equation $x^3+x-y^2=0$. Thus
the function field is a degree $3$ extension of $\Bbb C(y)$.

This behaviour is quite typical. If you like consider the rational curve
$y^2=x^3$: its function field is $\Bbb C(t)$ where $t=y/x$, $y=t^3$ and
$x=t^2$. Then $|\Bbb C(t):\Bbb C(x)|=|\Bbb C(t):\Bbb C(t^2)|=2$
and $|\Bbb C(t):\Bbb C(y)|=|\Bbb C(t):\Bbb C(t^3)|=3$.

Comment: Thanks for those examples. They don't quite answer my question though: is it correct that the residue fields of $\mathbb{A}^n$ at nonclosed points are transcendence degree n-1 extensions of $k$?

Comment: In $\Bbb A^n$ they can be of any transcendence degree from $0$ to $n$. @Arbutus

Comment: How is that possible? If $f\in k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$ is irreducible then the function field can be written as the fraction field of $R[x_n]/(g(x_n))$, where $R=k[x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1}]$ and $g(x_n)=f\in R[x_n]$. Doesn't taking the fraction field of $R[x_n]/(g(x_n))$ give a transcendence degree $n-1$ extension? How could you get transcendence degrees smaller than $n-1$?

Comment: very simple: the prime ideals of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ contain those of the form $(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$. The function field of that prime ideal is $k(x_{r+1},\ldots,x_n)$ of degree $n-r$. The transcendence degree is the dimension of the corresponding variety.

Comment: Fantastic. Yes, I was actually just about to answer my own comment! Thanks. I understand now.